#  How can i wait that a method or function finish to run its code?

Tags: objective-c

I need to find a solution for wait for a method or function finish to run its code. How can i do this?
Example : Method a, Method b.
I have to run b when a is finished!
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a();
b(); // will run only after a() is finished
```

Or you run them asynchronously?

Comment: I mean an Objective C functions or methods. Like : [object itsMethod];[object2 itsMethod];

Comment: @Andrea Lufino: Still the same.  The second method will not get invoked until after the first has finished.

Comment: Sure? i have a method that in its body call other 5 methods. [obj itsMethod];[obj2 itsMethod];[obj3 itsMethod]; ... but in my opinion the methods don't start when the previous has finished.